What movie has alien assassin feeding his own stomach "mouth"
I saw this movie when I was a kid and I was very creeped out by it. All I can remember is a White male, mid 30's, wearing black sunglasses and a black trench coat, who was secretly an alien, assassin. I can't remember how he came to Earth but I believe he was sent to kill someone. Anyways, there is this scene when he get's hungry and he sits down in a leather chair and lifts up his shirt only to reveal his stomach is a giant mouth, with large teeth and he "feeds" his stomach mouth. Another scene I remember with the same character is he is standing outside someone's house talking with a young woman about how to drive and a police officer says to the alien man "do you know the traffic laws?" to which the man reaches for a drivers manual and thumbs through it super fast and says "I now know every traffic law". 
It was a B-movie at best. If I had to guess the year I would say late 70's to mid 80's. I don't know any of the actors in it. I know the movie is NOT Alien, The Thing, or Total Recall. 

This sounds like Not of This Earth about an alien running around in a black coat and sunglasses, zapping people with his eyes to save his dying planet. There are actually 3 versions (a 1957 one by Roger Corman, a 1988 one with Traci Lords and one from 1995) and I think you're after the latter with Michael York and Richard Belzer, where the alien is eating stuff with a giant mouth in his stomach. Here's a video review with some clips from the film (slightly NSFW):




So Corman was actually involved in all 3 versions?  That's gotta be some kind of record for most remakes by the same guy.

Incredible, you found it! Thanks Walt.
